# Como não repetir valores numa lista em Python?

Tags: python, lista

Se eu crio duas listas, e depois somo as duas, eu crio uma terceira que possui todos os itens das duas anteriores:

```
>>>a = [1, 2, 3]
>>>b = [3, 4, 5]
>>>c = a + b
>>>print c
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```

Como faço para que o `3` não seja repetido na lista `c`? Preciso criar um código que pegue os itens de uma lista e some todos os seus valores, mas minha lista possui itens repetidos, e assim não está correto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A coleção adequada para lidar com elementos que não têm repetições é o **conjunto**. Você pode criar um conjunto em Python usando a função global `set`.

```
>>> a  = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [3, 4, 5]
>>> c = set(a + b)
>>> print(c)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Caso precise que o resultado seja realmente uma lista, faça `list(set(a + b))`.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Mas tem alguma forma de fazer isso sem a função set? Pois ela ainda não foi vista nas minhas aulas.

Comment: Aí sua pergunta cai mais na área de algoritmos. Sugiro abrir uma nova pergunta, pois essa aqui, do jeito que está, ainda pode ser útil pra muita gente no futuro.

Comment: Ótimo então! Agradecido!

Answer (score 1):

Se você precisa manter a ordem, acessar os índices da lista e você está lidando com listas no seu projeto, você não é obrigado a usar `set()`. Existe uma solução simples usando `dict.fromkeys()` para remover as repetições:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [3, 4, 5]
>>> c = a + b
>>> mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(c))
>>> print(mylist)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

As listas em Python não têm nenhuma função para detectar valores duplicados. O tipo apropriado é o [set](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

```py
>>>a = [1, 2, 3]
>>>b = [3, 4, 5]
>>>c = set(a + b)
>>>print(c)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>>type(c)
<class 'set'>
>>> c = list(set(a + b))
>>>print(c)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>type(c)
<class 'list'>
```

Não é possível adicionar novos valores duplicados ao set **c**, a menos que seja transformado em lista com `list()`.

---

O jeito (ineficiente) para replicar esta funcionalidade para o teu caso específico sem usar `set()` é iterar pela nova lista e não adicionar os valores impertinentes:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 4, 5]
c = a
for item in b:
    if item not in a:
        c.append(item)
print(c)
```

Ou com compreensão de lista:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 4, 5]
c = a + [item for item in b if item not in a]
print(c)
```

Resultado:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Nos três exemplos a lista gerada não é ordenada.