# Tamanho de listas de tuplas em um df

Tags: python, pandas, tupla

Tenho o seguinte df

```
n_words                       Words                        .
   220     [('trabalho', 17), ('monitor', 17), ('via', 16... 
  3114     [('atend', 863), ('ortopedico', 863), ('proced... 
     5     [('anomalos', 2), ('feixes', 1), ('eletrofisio... 
     3     [('hr', 1), ('sistema', 1), ('fenotipagem'...
```

Preciso da quantidade de palavras diferentes, ou seja, o tamanho de cada lista de tupla.

Tentei:

```
df['palvras_dif'] = ""
i = 0
for row in df['Words']:
    df['palvras_dif'][i] = len(df['Words'][i])
    i+=1
df
```

Mas não faz a contagem correta. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Está utilizando o Pandas?

Comment: Estou utilizando sim!

Comment: E o que representa o número em cada tupla? Ele deve ser considerado também ou apenas a palavra?

Comment: É a frequencia que a palavra apareceu em outro df. Exemplo: na linha 3 tinha uma lista com [''anomalos', 'eletrofisioterapia', 'feixes', 'anomalos', 'eletrofisioterapia'] e fiz a lista de tuplas com a palavra e a frquencia dela. Preciso saber qts palavras são diferentes, por isso, queria o tamanho da lista de tuplas...

Comment: Mas deve ser considerado ou não? Por exemplo, se houver `('trabalho', 2)` e `('trabalho', 14)`, deverá ser considerado como a mesma palavra ou como ocorrências distintas?

Comment: Nesse exemplo que você deu, não tenho a mesma palavra 2x, justamente pq o número é a frequencia da palavra.

Comment: Então não bastaria somar os valores em `n_words`?

Comment: Não pq em n_words tenho o número total de palavras, considerando também as  repetidas. Preciso do número de palavras distintas. Como o exemplo da linha 3:  ´[''anomalos', 'eletrofisioterapia', 'feixes', 'anomalos', 'eletrofisioterapia']´, tenho ´n_words´=5 e preciso do número das palavras diferentes, que seria: 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assim como discutido em:

- [Conferir se todos os itens de uma string são diferentes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/201758/5878)
- [Removendo elementos duplicados em uma lista com python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192567/5878)
- [Como não repetir valores numa lista em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118945/5878)

Você pode utilizar o tipo `set` do Python que, por definição, não possui elementos repetidos.

Utilize `p[0] for palavras in df['Words'] for p in palavras` para buscar todas as palavras do *dataframe*. Após, gere um conjunto a partir desses dados e verifique o seu tamanho:

```
num_palavras = len(set(p[0] for palavras in df['Words'] for p in palavras))
```

Por exemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Words': [
        [('a', 1), ('b', 2)],
        [('c', 1), ('d', 2)],
    ]
})

num_palavras = len(set(p[0] for palavras in df['Words'] for p in palavras))

print(num_palavras)  # 4
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/BarrenBowedInterfaces)</sup>

Mas, como [comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/355307/tamanho-de-listas-de-tuplas-em-um-df?noredirect=1#comment711708_355307), as palavras não irão se repetir pelas diferentes linhas, então bastaria verificar a quantidade de tuplas presentes no *dataframe*.

```
num_palavras = sum(len(palavras) for palavras in df['Words'])
```

Comment: Consegui!! Muito obrigada, Anderson!!